# Definition dynamic resource key by enum in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

here is my enums for resource key.

```
public enum UOCResKeys                  
{
    DicView_FontFamily = 10000,         
    DicView_BaseFontSize,               
    DicView_TitleFontSize,              
    DicView_TitleFontWeight,            
    DicView_SubtitleFontSize,           
    DicView_SubtitleForeGround,         
}
```

and following codes are refrencing resource by key.

```
ResourceDictionary appRes = Application.Current.Resources;
appRes[UOCResKeys.DicView_FontFamily] = new FontFamily(set.FontFamily);
```

like this way, how can i refrence a resource key defined by enum in xaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`x:Static` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx):

```xml
{DynamicResource {x:Static namespace:UOCResKeys.DicView_FontFamily}}
```

If the enum is defined in a class instead of a namespace, you can modify the path like this:

```xml
{DynamicResource {x:Static namespace:MyClass+UOCResKeys.DicView_FontFamily}}
```